# Two Port parameters on an Op Amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, analysis

I am asked to find the [h-harameters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-port_network#Hybrid_parameters_.28h-parameters.29) for this op amp:
[image]

I found the gain to be 1.87*Vi (where Vi = the input source). However I don't know how to do two port parameters with op amps, we've only covered basic circuits (Resistors, inductors, and capacitors.)

How can I find the h-params of the circuit above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to define what H parameters you want and exactly what they mean.  The H parameters for transistors, for example, don't apply.  Hfe stands for "H-forward-emitter" meaning the forward (input to output) characteristic in the common emitter configuration.  Obviously that makes no sense for a opamp circuit like you show.

You show a opamp circuit, but ultimately this has only a single connection.  Most H parameters don't make any sense for this since you can reduce this circuit to a Thevening voltage source, or equivalently, to a Norton current source.

H parameters are generally the ratio of two characteristics.  You could make a case for specifying the H parameter looking backwards into the output (since that's all this circuit presents to the outside world).  If you consider the output of this circuit to be a voltage, then this H-reverse parameter would the ratio of the change in output voltage to a small change in the output current.  Note that this is in units of Ohms, and is exactly the Norton or Thevenin impedance of the single source this circuit is.  This is why, again, it makes more sense to describe this circuit as a Thevenin or Norton source, depending on whether you view it as a voltage or current source, respectively.